# checking null in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have this code in typescript:

```
console.log ('collection[0]  -> ' + collection[0] );
console.log ('collection[0] !== null -> ' + collection[0] !== null);
```

but this is the result on the console:

```
console.log src/services/service.ts:122
  collection[0]  -> null
console.log src/services/service.ts:123
  true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet your `collection[0]` is a string containing `'null'`, not the primitive value `null`. Try:

```
console.log (collection[0] !== 'null');
```

It could also be an object that results in `'null'` when cast to string:

```
const item = collection[0];
const isWeirdNullObj = typeof item === 'object' && item !== null && String(item) === 'null';
```

This could happen with something like the following:

```js
const item = {
  valueOf() {
    return 'null';
  }
};
console.log('item is ' + item);
console.log(typeof item);
```

Comment: same result :-)

Comment: Check its type: `typeof collection[0]`

Comment: typeof collection[0] -> object

Comment: Guess it's an object that results in `'null'` when cast to string. Pretty weird

Comment: Did this actually solve the problem? I think my answer is wrong, and that [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59642037/11081214) is right

Answer (score 1):

> Addition operator has precedence over the equality operator.

So, in your code the addition operation is being evaluated first. Try the following :-

```
console.log ('collection[0] !== null -> ' + (collection[0] !== null));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have been burned by JavaScript's type coercion. The `+` operator in JS has a lot of operations associated with it. I suggest you don't `concat` with it and string interpolate instead.

```js
console.log(`collection[0] !== null -> ${collection[0] !== null}`);
```

Your other option is to separate out the two operations with a comma. `console.log` can take an arbitrary number of arguments and combines them for you

```js
console.log ('collection[0] !== null -> ', collection[0] !== null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `,` instead of `+` if you want to log some variable:

```js
var collection = [null];
console.log ('collection[0]  -> ', collection[0] );
console.log ('collection[0] !== null -> ', collection[0] !== null);
```